# Performance comparison of binary search tree functions

Tags: functional-programming, ocaml, binary-tree, tree-search

I have these two binary search tree search functions. My question is which one of these functions are more efficient, or if they are equivalent?

Given

```
type 'a tree = 
  | Empty
  | Node of 'a * 'a tree * 'a tree
```

1. 

```
let rec search x t =
  match t with
  | Empty -> Empty
  | Node(a, left, right) as t' ->
      if a = x then t'
      else 
        match search x left with
        | Empty -> search x right
        | t'' -> t''
```

2. 

```
let rec search x tree = 
  match tree with 
  | Empty -> Empty
  | Node (root, left, right) as t -> 
      if (x = root) then t 
      else if (x < root) then search x left
      else search x right
```

I think that the second one is equivalent simply because we don't need to have another match with `Empty` since we already have it before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### It depends

This really depends on whether values in your binary tree are strictly ordered. Your first function will search the right branch if the value is not found in the left branch. The second will only follow either the left *or* the right branch, but not both.

They are *not* equivalent.

### Performance and stack considerations

If we assume strict ordering then the first function will be less efficient as it will search all nodes. Performance will be O(n) while with the second function, performance will be O(log n). The first function is also not tail-recursive, so you run the risk of a stack overflow for a very large tree.

If you want to make this tail-recursive, one approach is to maintain a stack or worklist of nodes to deal with and work through them as we go. We search left branches first, pushing the right branches onto the stack. Once we hit an `Empty` left branch, we start consuming the stack.

```
let rec search x t stack =
  match t, stack with
  | Empty, [] -> Empty
  | Empty, n::ns -> search x n ns
  | Node (v, _, _), _ when x = v -> t
  | Node (_, l, r), _ -> search x l @@ r :: stack
```

We can hide the `stack` argument by making this a local function.

```
let search x t =
  let rec search' x t stack =
    match t, stack with
    | Empty, [] -> Empty
    | Empty, n::ns -> search' x n ns
    | Node (v, _, _), _ when x = v -> t
    | Node (_, l, r), _ -> search' x l @@ r :: stack
  in
  search' x t []
```

### A further suggestion

If we can assume strict ordering in the tree, I would probably suggest the following, using conditional guards.

```
let rec search x t =
  match t with
  | Empty -> Empty
  | Node (v, _, _) when x = v -> t
  | Node (v, l, _) when x < v -> search x l
  | Node (_, _, r) -> search x r
```

Which we can reduce to:

```
let rec search x = function
  | Empty -> Empty
  | Node (v, _, _) as t when x = v -> t
  | Node (v, l, _) when x < v -> search x l
  | Node (_, _, r) -> search x r
```

Comment: But how can with your code for the strictly ordered BST to match multiple matches? Isn't match/with acting like if else?

Comment: `match` is _not_ if/else. The former allows for concisely destructuring data structures. The latter deals with boolean conditions. Both are control flow mechanisms, and anything that can be written using one can be written using the other, but they do it in different ways.

Comment: I'm also not sure what you mean by multiple matches. Do you want to return all matching nodes in a list? A strictly ordered BST generally shouldn't have multiple nodes with the same value.

Comment: I see, so your last suggestion of conditional guards is an alternative to my 2. function in case of strict ordering? Why prefer that to if else if else?

Comment: Perhaps a bit of personal preference. I find less nesting easier to mentally parse. Also, being able to use `_` wildcard patterns tells my practiced eyes which pieces of data actually matter in each case.

Comment: that s fair. I agree.

Comment: The 1. would work for binary tree (not search, so not ordering) how would you optimize that function to be more readable? Because for binary trees, the time complexity would be O(n) surely

Comment: In your first function, the `as t'` is redundant. You have access to that value through the `t` binding. You could have that pattern be: `Node (a, _, _) when a = x -> t` and then after that `Node (_, l, r) -> ...`

Comment: Right, I asked a separate question https://stackoverflow.com/staging-ground/75980345